# Filling List<List<Integer>> from second dimension first

Tags: java, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I have `List<List<Integer>>` called `test`. I want to fill it up from the second dimension as is seen in the (incorrect) code below.

One solution which is obvious is to *firstly* create two separate `List<Integer>` that are equal to `{1,...,100}` and then use `test.add( ... )` two times to get the desired object. However, I'm looking for a non-hacky solution since in my case I have multitudinous lists that need to be added to the second dimension of `test`.

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> test = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            test.get(0).add(i);
            test.get(1).add(i);
        }

    }
}
```

What I want to end up with is to be able to call `test.get(0)` and `test.get(1)` that both return the list of integers: `{1,...,100}`.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I had an error in the code I put up that's now fixed. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1):

You must be looking for something like this? Here `i` represents the 1st dimension and `j` represents the 2nd. And below code forms `2x100` 2d array list

```
    List<List<Integer>> test = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    for(int i=0; i< 2; i++) {
        test.add(i, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        for(int j = 1; j <= 100; j++) {
            test.get(i).add(j);
        }
    }
```